# How do I return a resultset using Jersey JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am running a query to return State, City, and Zip from my database. How do I get JAX-RS (Jersey) to return this like this;

```
<State>
   <City>
      <Zip></Zip>
   </City>
</State>
```

and so on......

Do I need to build an object that matches my xml structure, then pass that to JAX-RS, or can JAX-RS build it for me based on the resultset?

Answer (score 0):

No, Jersey can't create the output directly from a ResultSet. That's because it has no idea how the data is supposed to be represented. You'll have to write a class to hold the results. You can use JAXB annotations on that class to provide greater control over how the XML looks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use POJOs in your JAX-RS service.  Then use JPA to map the objects to the database, and JAXB to map them to XML.  For an example see:

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)